# Mapping keyCodes together

Tags: javascript

```
const controls = {
    87: false, // W
    83: false, // S
    68: false, // D
    65: false, // A
    38: false, // Arrow up
    40: false, // Arrow down
    39: false, // Arrow right
    37: false, // Arrow left
};

document.body.addEventListener('keyup', keyUp, false);
document.body.addEventListener('keydown', keyDown, false);

function keyUp(event) {
    controls[event.keyCode] = false;
}

function keyDown(event) {
    controls[event.keyCode] = true;
}
```

I have added the ability to use both arrow keys and WASD keys to control player movement in my game. Currently, I'm checking for `W` and `Arrow Up`, `S` and `Arrow Down` (and so on) at the same time in my game logic.

```
if (controls[87] || controls[38]) { }

if (controls[83] || controls[40]) { }

if (controls[68] || controls[39]) { }

if (controls[65] || controls[37]) { }
```

Is there a way to map the Arrow Keys to the WASD keys instead of redundantly checking for two at the same time?

Example: From this...

```
if (controls[87] || controls[38]) { }
```

...to this:

```
if (controls[87]) { }
```

Comment: You can think of creating a object , in a way  like this :   

const controls = {
    '87|38': false, // W
      '83|40': false, // S
      '68|39': false, // D
      '65|37': false, //A
};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no one keycode for both W and UP arrow and so on.

You can create function like this:

```
function isKeyCodeUp(keyCode) {
    return keyCode === controls[87] || keyCode === controls[38];
}
```

And then just call it:

```
if (isKeyCodeUp(event.keyCode)) {
```

Another decorator for the problem:

```
if ([87,38].includes(event.keyCode)) {
```

OR

```
const KEYCODE_UP = [87,38];
if (KEYCODE_UP.includes(event.keyCode)) {
```

Comment: Isn't this more or less the same with a function call as an extra step?

Comment: It is. There is no other work-around for your question. Added another example.

Comment: Would you consider this a bad solution? https://hasteb.in/ajumixan.js

Comment: Yes. It leads to confusion "why the number is 87 if I stroke 38".

Comment: I found a better solution but I'm accepting your answer because you seem like a nice lad.